# Class Not Found Exception(FX7500 SDK)

Tags: java, rfid

I have been trying to run the SDK provided by Zebra(FX7500 Embedded SDK Installer-1.2.2) following their guide.

the terminal window shows the "Listening at port 8998 ". But when I click to debug it just throw classNotFound Exception at Main class.

The [Eclipse Exception Window](https://developer.zebra.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/96959-18791/FX7500_Class_not_found_exception.png) depicts the scenario. Can u pls guide us on how to run this sample application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need code and the full exception message as text, not as a picture.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. this is a sample application developed by Zebra.  the className is: RFIDSample4App. and the exception says "source not found" while debug

Comment: The file does not appear to be in the correct package location.